# Set textview inside doINBackground android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I am having a main class A, from which i create an object to class B extending Asynctask. Have set content view in A. Now in doInBackground of B, i want to update the textView of A, but its giving

`Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Exception. I tried declaring the setcontentview in B as well, but no use, can anyone please tell how to edit the textview of A in B??

Comment: Try to do it in onPostExecute function of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setText()` from the UI thread, so either from `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` or in `onProgressUpdate()`

You could also use a `runOnUiThread()` handler in `doInBackground()`, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using an AsyncTask.

Comment: But, i am updating this textview as and when the progressbar update, so need to have in do in background only!

Comment: @bharath Then use `publishProgress()` to pass the information to `onProgressUpdate()` and upadte it from there.

Comment: But i cant pass numbers through publish, it takes void na?

Comment: @bharath You can pass `Integer...` parameters to onProgressUpdate() through publishProgress(). Its all given in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

override onProgressUpdate and call publishProgress in doInBackground

Answer (score 2):

If the text update has to do with progress information, then you could use `publishProgress()`/`onProgressUpdate()` for that.

If it's not a progress update in a wider sense then I'm with Raghav -- you should consider another approach then.

Answer (score 0):

We should not perform any ui changes in the doinBackgroud. You should and can perform in post execute. and also you can set notification in preexecute or onProgressUpdate.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

doInBackground is work thread. You have handle View in UI thread. please do it in `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate`. All these are working in UI Thread.

Of course you can pass Integer to `onProgressUpdate`. please notice the second paramters: `AysncTask<Void, Integer, VOid>,` the second parameter means the `onProgressUpdate` parameter type

Comment: thanks, but on progress update, it accepts only voids, i need to pass a integer value to that, is it possible?